# Как сделать плавную анимацию при появлении?

Tags: css

Привет!
Как плавно увеличивать по высоте блок:

```css
.b-form__group--form-comment {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
b-input--new-comment {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 56px;
  padding: 15px 10px 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
}
.b-form__group--add-file {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.b-label--add-file {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.b-input--add-file[type=file] {
  display: none;
}
.b-form__group.b-form__group--form-comment:hover .b-form__group--add-file {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-form__group b-form__group--form-comment">
  <textarea placeholder="Type message…" class="b-input b-input--new-comment"></textarea>


  <div class="b-form__group b-form__group--add-file">
    <label for="add-file" class="b-label b-label--add-file">Add files</label>
    <input type="file" id="add-file" class="b-input b-input--add-file">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для анимации нужно задать начальное и конечное значение свойства max-height.

```css
.b-form__group--form-comment {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
.b-input--new-comment {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 56px;
  padding: 15px 10px 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
}
.b-form__group--add-file {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: static;
  max-height: 0px;
  transition: 1s;
}
.b-label--add-file {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.b-input--add-file[type=file] {
  display: none;
}
.b-form__group.b-form__group--form-comment:hover .b-form__group--add-file {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  max-height: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-form__group b-form__group--form-comment">
  <textarea placeholder="Type message…" class="b-input b-input--new-comment"></textarea>


  <div class="b-form__group b-form__group--add-file">
    <label for="add-file" class="b-label b-label--add-file">Add files</label>
    <input type="file" id="add-file" class="b-input b-input--add-file">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а как сделать что бы в обратную сторону так же плавно уменьшался?

Comment: @drtvader Изменил код: добавил анимацию параметра height для b-form__group--form-comment

Comment: К сожалению высота не ограничена может быть. У меня есть еще какие-то варианты?

Comment: Нужно думать, сейчас на работе, времени пока что нет. Приду домой, попробую посмотреть

Comment: Спасибо! или может тут уже js анимация нужна?

Comment: Нашёл. Изменил для .b-form__group--add-file параметр position на static, анимация работает в обе стороны

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь все как надо работает!